# how to access and view the hbase table properties in Java?

Tags: java, hbase

I am trying to access the HBase table through java and list down all the properties of a HBase table?
How to access and view the HBase table properties in Java?

Comment: By accessing and listing down all the properties of a HBase table. Thrice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use HTable interface

```
HTable htable = new HTable(conf, "my_table");
HTableDescriptor descriptor = htable.getTableDescriptor();
HColumnDescriptor[] columns = descriptor.getColumnFamilies();
```